# issue on Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I have upgrade swift 2.3 to swift 3, and i got this error

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' swift3

here code

```
var cellDescriptors: [[String:Any]]!

    func loadCellDescriptors() {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ProfileDescriptor", ofType: "plist") {
        cellDescriptors = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: path)
        getIndicesOfVisibleRows()



        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}


if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["isExpanded"] as! Bool == false {
            shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = true
        }
```

i got error on this line

```
if cellDescriptors[indexPath.section][indexOfTappedRow]["isExpanded"] as! Bool == false
```

Give me any suggestion how can i solve this

Comment: thanks for reply but i already try it but it's not work

Comment: not solved got error

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: can you post your plist ProfileDescriptor file format ?

Comment: ok i will paste file here

Comment: here is link https://www.dropbox.com/s/79fe96yaed7v5rl/CellDescriptor.plist?dl=0

Comment: `NSArray(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CellDescriptor", ofType: "plist")!) as? [[[String: Any]]] ?? []` is correct

Comment: Notice that you are trying it with another plist called ProfileDescriptor. Don't forget to declare it as `var cellDescriptors: [[[String: Any]]] = [ ]`

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a chain of subscriptions in Swift 3 without telling the compiler the intermediate types

```
let section = cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! [Any]
let rowItem = section[indexOfTappedRow] as! [String:Any]
if rowItem["isExpanded"] as! Bool == false {
        shouldExpandAndShowSubRows = true
}
```

And as always, never use the mutable Foundation collection types `NSMutableArray/Dictionary` in Swift unless you have absolutely no choice. They cannot be bridged to Swift and they lack type information.

Comment: thanks for it when i  declare  let section = cellDescriptors[indexPath.section] as! [Any]   i got this error Cast from '[String : Any]' to unrelated type '[Any]' always fails

Comment: Then your chaining is wrong. According to your code `cellDescriptors` is supposed to contain an array because `indexOfTappedRow` seems to be an integer. `[String:Any]` is subscripted by key (`String`)